# Google chrome javascript loaded via ajax only runs after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I got a very odd problem which only happens on google chrome.
Due to the size of the project i cannot really supply a test-case (believe me i tried).
The problem is that after loading some html (containing scripts) into a container with an ajax call like this:

```
var fillView = function(data) {
    viewElement.html(data);
}

$.ajax({
    url: gridUrl + 'update/id/' + rowData.id + gridUrlParams,
    success: fillView
});
```

...all the javascript that was in `data` does not get executed in google chrome **until i click onto the document**. This goes for several different plugins bound to input fields in a form. I can't observe (or reproduce, for that matter) any such effect in any other browser, nor did i add any code that would do something like that.

I tried for hours to get to the core of this, removing the first half of the affected input fields, then the other half, then portions of it.. only to have this happen to whatever remains. I also tried stripping down/commenting out most of the other javascript i didn't need (which shouldn't and wasn't called) for the current site.

There seems to be a rather obvious "fix" that isn't a fix and also only sometimes works. in case you didn't guess it ;):

```
setTimeout("$('#form').trigger('click')",50);
```

Funny/Odd Detail:

If i add `alert("test");` to the javascript, it get's executed right at page load, but stuff affecting the UI does not until the first click anywhere in the browser.

**$%*&*§$}$!!!!**

UPDATE:

adding the following:

```
    $('.field-block').css('background-color','#000');
```

to the result of the ajax call, also does nothing until i click inside the browser window.

"My Latin ends here." Has anyone ever heard of this, seen it or has an idea what i could try to fix this pesky problem.

Comment: The fact that the alert gets executed makes me think that you have some other issue that is inside the JS that you are appending. Have you tried anything simple like changing the body's styles or something like?

Comment: what kind of issue do you mean? there are no errors@ the console. Please see my edit

Comment: Maybe you have debugger enabled? Maybe there are weird Google Chrome addons preventing direct script execution?

Comment: No debugger enabled && "Boo... You have no extensions :-("

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was a details tag around the affected inputs.. The polyfill in firefox and others worked great, seems natively they are not ready for production use yet.